# Wifi speed is not slow

Tags: wireless

wifi speed is slow laptop in which ubuntu 16.04 lts has been installed. i observed that wifi speed is as expected in other devices but on laptop it is very slow. Internet speed is fine if i use it through  enthernet but for me it is not very convenient since i have to travel a lot.

so please help me to solve my query

here are my laptop network specification

[image]

Comment: DO NOT post image of text which can be easily copied and pasted here, It makes it hard to read :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

And then reboot and check the results.

Comment: The speed remains the same.  There is not much difference in the previous value.

Comment: I checked almost every post I found with your wifi card... the result is that you have to chose between no wifi and slow wifi. See it here too: http://www.stevenmaude.co.uk/posts/my-wifis-connected-but-theres-no Almost everywhere I looked this card have problems with linux...